# Count multiple characters in a string separately

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, letter

My teacher has asked me to write a function to count the occurrences of a string by using another strings letters. So for example:

```
>>>problem3("all is quiet on the western front", "tqe")
>>>["t=4", "q=1", "e=4"]
```

however I can only get it to do:

```
>>>problem3("all is quiet on the western front", "tqe")
>>>[4, 1, 4]
```

This is my code:

```
def problem3(myString, charString):
    return [myString.count(x) for x in (charString)]
```

How do I get it in this format ["t=4", "q=1", "e=4"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are just being asked to format it very specifically and you are close, just need to format the result:

```
def problem3(myString, charString):
    return ['{}={}'.format(x, myString.count(x)) for x in charString]

>>> problem3("all is quiet on the western front", "tqe")
['t=4', 'q=1', 'e=4']
```